# Javascript stacked grouped graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am looking for cheap/free alternatives to ChartJS and Highcharts

I need to compare two objects, with their expenses sumed up(while still being presented)
Both mentioned API's can do that, but they are quite expensive.

Comment: Check out [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/)? We've been using it in production for some time now and have been very happy with it.

Comment: no stacked while being grouped

Comment: You should probably add an image for what you're trying to do, it's not 100% clear.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [d3.js](http://d3js.org/).  It's free, powerful and widely-used.  Here are some examples of d3.js rendering of stacked/grouped graphs:

- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768
- http://strongriley.github.io/d3/ex/stack.html
- http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBar.html

Andy

Comment: no stacked while being grouped again